# How to Show Game Center's Player Profile View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, game-center

My application uses ios game center credentials to login into application. 
And need to implement logout functionality. According to Game Center API it's not possible to logout user programmatiically.

So, is it possible to show game center's player profile view? In this case user will logout by yourself.(using standard Game Center view).

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, it might also be a good feature to allow the user to disable Game Center within your own app.  In other words, they remain logged into Game Center, but your app treats them as if they were not, or as if Game Center doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this to open the Game Center app and load the "me" tab.  At the bottom of the view the user can tap on their account name and Log Out.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:/me/account"]];
```

Unfortunately, this takes the user outside your app.

Comment: Also found how to logout by opening URL scheme:     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:/me/signout"]];

Comment: Is it possible to do the following command without opening Game Center? "gamecenter:/me/signout"

Comment: I haven't tried it.  Can you try it and post the results here?  Try also "gamecenter:/me/logout" and maybe some other combos like "gamecenter:/me/account/logout".